# Filter facet terms based on their length when using scripts in Elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

I want to create a terms facet which returns results only for terms of length greater than a certain value. Ideally it would look something like:

```
 "facets": {
    "myFacet": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "content",
        "size": 10,
        "script": "term.length > 3 ? true: false"
      }
    }
  }
```

However, the MVEL scripting language doesn't seem to like the term.**length** property. Is there another way to achieve this? The MVEL docs don't provide much info on this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to error from elasticsearch (`Error: could not access: length; in class: java.lang.String`) mvel delegates `length` to `java.lang.String` class, so you should use [java.lang.String#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method.

```
"facets": {
  "myFacet": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "content",
      "size": 10,
      "script": "term.length() > 3 ? true: false"
    }
  }
}
```